# Write an application to Encrypt/ decrypt various web.config (vb.net)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-config

I'm trying to write an application that will encrypt and decrypt a web.config which has been selected.

I have found some code to do this within an application like so...

Imports System
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Configuration

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    'encrypt/decrypt identity
    Dim config As Configuration
    Dim configSection As ConfigurationSection

    'encrypt identity
    config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath)
    If Not (config Is Nothing) Then
        configSection = config.GetSection("system.web/identity")
        If Not (configSection Is Nothing) Then
            If Not (configSection.SectionInformation.IsLocked) Then
                configSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")
                config.Save()
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'decrypt identity
    config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath)
    configSection = config.GetSection("system.web/identity")
    If Not (configSection Is Nothing) Then
        If Not (configSection.SectionInformation.IsLocked) Then
            configSection.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection()
            config.Save()
        End If
    End If
```

What i wanted to do was put this in a win forms application with a couple of buttons (btnEncrypt and btndecrypt) and a browse control (to browse to the various web.configs).

The application can then be used by our ops guys so they can encrypt or decrypt all the web.configs in all our web applications without having to re-publish etc...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Or use this one that's all been done for you: http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/07/16/encrypt-your-web-config-please/

Comment: thanks i ll have a look at that at home - i m being blocked from that site at work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft [has a built in way to already encrypt parts of your web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx). There's no need to re-invent the wheel.

If you wanted to build an admin interface to see those settings, then that's easy too. Since it decrypts it in memory (when it's being processed), you can get the relevant sections and dump them into an admin interface.  Be advised that any actual change to the web.config will cause an AppPool recycle.

Comment: the thing is i want to encrypt identity impersonator so people within the company can't see the username and password - except for ops who may have to change certain passwords etc...

Comment: i'm quite new to this i'm afraid - is their not a way of making a application to do this?

Comment: @Anna it's just far easier to encrypt that section of the web.config.  If "Ops" can see it, then build an admin interface that is only exposed to the 'ops' rule so they can see what it is.

Comment: @george would this mean publishing all the websites again? As we have a lot of web applications that have configs that need to be encrypted this will be very time consuming is there a better way or have i misunderstood?

Comment: No, you can run the encrypter on the target server (or as part of the build process).  It's a one time thing (until there's a change to the web.config). It's advisable to make this part of the build process if anything in the webconfig changes.

Comment: What i need is a generic encrypter/decrypter where i can look for the web.config (hopefully using a browse facility) within different applications which is not part of the compiler...

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: ok to try and explain.  I want to create a utility program which can look at the config files of all our web sites.  I would like the user to enter the path to the config file, and either encrypt or decrypt the file, without re-compiling the program, or modifying the individual web sites in any way.

Comment: You don't have to recompile the program to use the built in encryption. You don't have to modify the websites to use the built in encryption.  The built in utility I linked you to does exactly what you're asking it to do.

Comment: @George Thanks George once i understood what i needed to do this turned out to be the best solution thank you for your help!!